# Initializing two arrays of structs referencing each other

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

The program has multiple phases, and as one ends, a choice is made to pick a new one.

```
struct PhaseChoice;

 struct Phase {
    PhaseChoice* choices;
 };

 struct PhaseChoice {
    bool (*condition)();
    Phase* newPhase;
 };
```

...this forward declaration works okay. But I have trouble initializing it.

```
 Phase phases[2] = {
     { choices_p0 },
     { choices_p1 }
 }

 PhaseChoice choices_p0[2] = {
      { condition_p0p1, 
        &phases[1] },
      { condition_p0again, 
        &phases[0] },
 };

 PhaseChoice choices_p1[2] = {
      { condition_p1p0, 
        &phases[0] },
      { condition_p1again, 
        &phases[1] },
 };
```

This obviously fails, since while initializing `phases[2]` the program still has no clue about `choices_p0` or `choices_p1`. If I reverse the order, initializing `choices_p0` I'll encounter `&phases[1]` which is unknown as of yet.

What is the right way to initialize such structures?

Comment: C or C++? Choose one. Note: this is no valid C code.

Comment: @Olaf: Will the solution differ between the two languages?

Comment: The result of compilation will differ definitively: The C compiler will report an error. Even if you do it compatible, there are different way for each language. Just to repeat it: C and C++ are different languages. While you _can_ program C-like in C++, there are subtle differences for the same syntax. And _proper_ solutions in either language differ significantly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can easily be solved by *declaring* the `choices_p0` and `choices_p1` arrays before the definition of `phases`:

```
extern PhaseChoice choices_p0[2];
extern PhaseChoice choices_p1[2];

Phase phases[2] = {
    { choices_p0 },
    { choices_p1 }
};

PhaseChoice choices_p0[2] = { ... };
PhaseChoice choices_p1[2] = { ... };
```

You need the `extern` keyword for the declarations, or you define the arrays.

Comment: @SF. You do include the `extern` keyword in the forward declaration?

Comment: `error: redeclaration of 'PhaseChoice choices_p0 [2]'`  and `note:  previous declaration 'PhaseChoice {anonymous}::choices_p0 [2]'`

Comment: Yes. I copied the line verbatim, except with `extern` in front and `;` instead of `=`.

Comment: BTW, while the file with these is compiled under C++, the headers for these data types are included through `extern "C"`since they are to be used in a C program as well (common data structures between C++ and C).

Answer (score 1):

I would say, initialize them with invalid pointers and later assign on assign them.

```
Phase phases[2] = {
     { nullptr },
     { nullptr }
 }

 PhaseChoice choices_p0[2] = {
      { condition_p0p1, 
        &phases[1] },
      { condition_p0again, 
        &phases[0] },
 };

 PhaseChoice choices_p1[2] = {
      { condition_p1p0, 
        &phases[0] },
      { condition_p1again, 
        &phases[1] },
 };
phases[0] = choices_p0;
phases[1] = choices_p1
```